# multiple image upload not being saved in DB

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

i'm using primefaces 2.0 for multiple image upload like this:

```
             <h:form>
                  <p:fileUpload value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.image}" 
                                  fileUploadListener="#{newAuctionWizard.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                                  multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />

                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                </h:form>
```

I'm trying to display it:

```
       <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Auction in picture</f:facet>
                 <p:graphicImage value="#{auct.image}" style="max-height:15%; max-width:100%" />
        </p:column>
```

auct is retrieved from a SELECT List(SELECT a from Auction a)

I have a class Auction(@Entity) in which a store the images like this:

```
@Lob
private byte[] image;
```

I also created a wizard for the auction because i have multiple panels and done this:

```
    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        try {
            InputStream input = file.getInputStream();
            byte[] image = IOUtils.toByteArray(input); // Apache commons IO.
            auction.setImage(image);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
```

the problem is that the upload image(from myComputer) isn't saved in DB(when I look at the image column it shows NULL). I'm also using hibernate for ORM.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your image correctly uploaded to the server? Check the size of the image byte array (it shouldn't be null). Also, <p:graphicImage> should point to an image URL (e.g. http://localhost/server_root/img/myImg.png and not to an array of bytes (even if they represent an image)

Comment: read this example [Upload a file step by step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486157/get-uploaded-file-path-in-primefaces/39487964#39487964)

Comment: Seems you're not calling anything that would save it in the db. Like entitymanager.merge(auction)